# C++ Complicated look-up table

Tags: c++, lookup, lookup-tables

I have around 400.000 "items".
Each "item" consists of 16 double values.

At runtime I need to compare items with each other. Therefore I am muplicating their double values. This is quite time-consuming.

I have made some tests, and I found out that there are only 40.000 possible return values, no matter which items I compare with each other.

I would like to store these values in a look-up table so that I can easily retrieve them without doing any real calculation at runtime.

My question would be how to efficiently store the data in a look-up table.

The problem is that if I create a look-up table, it gets amazingly huge, for example like this:

```
 item-id, item-id, compare return value

 1    1    499483,49834
 1    2    -0.0928
 1    3    499483,49834
 (...)
```

It would sum up to around 120 million combinations.
That just looks too big for a real-world application.

But I am not sure how to avoid that.

Can anybody please share some cool ideas?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What does "I am muplicating their double values" mean? Are you saying the lookup is slow? What's wrong with an unordered_map?

Comment: Loading the double values from the file already is slower than I can afford, and the calculations finally put me over the edge.

Comment: So, you have something like: `typedef double[16] item`, and you do an operation that looks like `item a,b,c; for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){ c[i] = a[i] * b[i];}`, and this multiplication is too slow. Your goal is to get the result stored in `c` more efficiently. Is that all correct?

Comment: Yep, that is correct. There are only 40.000 different return values possible. I thought that I could somehow use this fact.

Comment: Looking things up might be as slow as multiplying - can we speed up the file reading instead?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand you correctly, You have two inputs with 400K possibilities, so 400K * 400K = 160B entries... assuming you have them indexed sequentially, and the you stored your 40K possibilities in a way that allowed 2-octets each, you're looking at a table size of roughly 300GB... pretty sure that's beyond current every-day computing.  So, you might instead research if there is any correlation between the 400K "items", and if so, if you can assign some kind of function to that correlation that gives you a clue (read: hash function) as to which of the 40K results might/could/should result.  Clearly your hash function and lookup needs to be shorter than just doing the multiplication in the first place.  Or maybe you can reduce the comparison time with some kind of intelligent reduction, like knowing the result under certain scenarios.  Or perhaps some of your math can be optimized using integer math or boolean comparisons.  Just a few thoughts...

Answer (score 0):

To speed things up, you should probably compute all of the possible answers, and store the inputs to each answer.

Then, I would recommend making some sort of look up table that uses the answer as the key(since the answers will all be unique), and then storing all of the possible inputs that get that result.

To help visualize:

Say you had the table 'Table'.  Inside Table you have keys, and associated to those keys are values.  What you do is you make the keys have the type of whatever format your answers are in(the keys will be all of your answers).  Now, give your 400k inputs each a unique identifier.  You then store the unique identifiers for a multiplication as one value associated to that particular key.  When you compute that same answer again, you just add it as another set of inputs that can calculate that key.

Example:

```
Table<AnswerType, vector<Input>>
```

Define Input like:

```
struct Input {IDType one, IDType two}
```

Where one 'Input' might have ID's 12384, 128, meaning that the objects identified by 12384 and 128, when multiplied, will give the answer.

So, in your lookup, you'll have something that looks like:

```
AnswerType lookup(IDType first, IDType second)
{
    foreach(AnswerType k in table)
    {
        if table[k].Contains(first, second)
            return k;
    }
}

// Defined elsewhere
bool Contains(IDType first, IDType second)
{
    foreach(Input i in [the vector])
    {
        if( (i.one == first && i.two == second ) ||
            (i.two == first && i.one == second )
            return true;
    }
}
```

I know this isn't real C++ code, its just meant as pseudo-code, and it's a rough cut as-is, but it might be a place to start.

While the foreach is probably going to be limited to a linear search, you can make the 'Contains' method run a binary search by sorting how the inputs are stored.

In all, you're looking at a run-once application that will run in O(n^2) time, and a lookup that will run in nlog(n).  I'm not entirely sure how the memory will look after all of that, though.  Of course, I don't know much about the math behind it, so you might be able to speed up the linear search if you can somehow sort the keys as well.